# SimpleMembership Get Custom Column Values with Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I customized `UserProfile` Table and added new column called `IsActive`. It works fine with registration. 
And now i want to get value of that custom column `IsActive` before login.

```
WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)
```

Need these scenario

1. Check if the username and password is valid
2. If the login is valid then check if the user is active.
3. If the user is not active it should not login.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just off the top of my head and untested, so it may not be 100% correct, but it should put you in the right direction.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    using(var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var user = db.UserProfile.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == model.UserName);
            if(user != null)
            {   
                if(user.IsActive == true)
                {
                    if(ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            return View("SomeView");
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            // handle exception
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("SomeView");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
    return View("SomeView");
}
```